# Forced to iterate over a generator to see the exception

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, generator, pytest

I have a basic generator function that raises an exception if its parameters are not correct before doing any `yield`.

```
def my_generator(n):
    if not isistance(n, int):
        raise TypeError("Expecting an integer")

    for i in range(1, 3):
        yield n
```

I wanted to cover my whole project with unit tests, so I implemented this test function:

```
import pytest
from my_package import my_generator

@pytest.mark.parametrize("n, expected_exception", [
    ("1", TypeError),  (1.0, TypeError), ([1], TypeError)
])
def test_my_generator_with_bad_parameters(n, expected_exception):
    with pytest.raises(expected_exception):
        my_generator(n)
```

But when I'm running pytest, I get:

> Failed: DID NOT RAISE

However, if I modify my test to iterate over the resulting generator, the test passes.

```
def test_my_generator_with_bad_parameters(n, expected_exception):
    res = my_generator(n)
    with pytest.raises(expected_exception):
        next(res)
```

How I am supposed to write this test? Is there a way to modify `my_generator` so that the first implementation of my unit test passes (assuming the function remains a generator)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, it's pretty OK to wait for the exception, until your generator is actually used, since most of the time, this is done in the same `for`-statement or `list` call.
If you really need checks at the time, your generator is generated, you can wrap your generator in an inner function:

```
def my_generator(n):
    if not isistance(n, int):
        raise TypeError("Expecting an integer")
    def generator():
        for i in range(1, 3):
            yield n
    return generator()
```

Comment: Can the downvoter explain what is wrong with this solution?